# when I go to the url that matches, component is not getting rendered react-routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I go to the url that matches the path or a route and the component in not getting rendered. I also have wrapped every thing with BrowserRouter in index.js file as well. Can't figure out the problem here. Help me pls.

Here is code

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
        <Route
          path="comments/:curPage"
          render={(props) => <List {...props} comments={comments} />}
        />
        <Route path="test" exact component={Test} />
      </Switch>
```

Here is index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "query-string": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-scroll-to-bottom": "^4.1.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I go to the url  `comments/1` The content in `<List />`  component is not getting rendered. Why?

Comment: It turned out that I was missing "/" in front of "comments/1", that's why the <List /> component was not rendered.

Comment: Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".